# About the tense usage in direct and indirect speech

Tags: tense, usage

I am saying i didnt do that .

I am sayinv i dont do that.

Which one is correct ?

What does the tense should be used when we change into indirect speech ?

I was saying "i killed her"

Indirect speech -from the third person -- he was saying he had killed her

Is this correct ?

She was saying she is going to do

Or
She was saying she was going to do

Which one is correct ?

Comment: [Please use a caps for the pronoun "I"]

Answer (score 0):

1. Both of these can be correct sentences.

"I am saying" - This is present tense so in both cases the "saying" is happening in the present.

"I didn't do that" - This is past tense. At some point in the past, you didn't do the thing.
"I don't do that" - This is present tense. You currently do not do it.

"I am saying that I didn't eat the spaghetti" - The spaghetti either hasn't been eaten or someone else ate the spaghetti.(Or you are lying)

"I am saying that I don't eat spaghetti" - At the present time, I do not eat any spaghetti as a rule. (e.g. If I am allergic to or dislike spaghetti.) If someone were to offer me some, I would decline.

2. Both of these sentences can be correct as well

"I was saying 'i killed her'" - The 'saying' and the killing both happened in the past.
"he was saying he had killed her" - The 'saying' and the killing both happened in the past here as well. The addition of had in this sentence makes little difference but can in other cases. See here for more info: [https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/#:~:text=The%20Past%20Perfect%20tense%20in,participle%20of%20the%20main%20verb](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/#:%7E:text=The%20Past%20Perfect%20tense%20in,participle%20of%20the%20main%20verb).

3. Both of these are gramatically correct but incomplete sentences. You need to add an object for the verd 'do' (Or change the verb)

"She was saying she is going to run" - The 'saying' happened in the past.

"is going to run" is future tense. The running will happen in the future.
Compared to the present, she said in the past that she would run in the future. Ading in times might make it clearer: She was saying yesterday that she will run next month.

"She was saying she was going to run" - The 'saying' happened in the past.

"was going to run" - This is the future in the past tense (More info: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html)
This means that in the past she was planning on running at some point in the future but in the present that action has now ended. For example: Last week she was saying that she was going to run yesterday.

These are quite complex tenses and I'm not sure if I explained the differences well or not so let me know if anything isn't clear or you would like more examples.

Comment: I think you explained the tenses well, it would be great if the OP could clarify what it is they are trying to achieve. "I'm saying <X>" is not a particularly common phrase to use unless you're either summarizing, reiterating or distancing yourself from something. I know a lot of people struggle with say and tell and I wonder in what situation the sentences came up here. Also maybe emphasize that "I don't eat spaghetti" is a statement of habit. It's not about the fact I'm not eating them now, it's about the fact that I don't like them or am allergic or am on a no spaghetti fast.

Comment: I am clear now but do quotations have any important role in this subject

Comment: @17RBECSE024M.JHANARANJAN I'm not sure I understand your question. I have included quotations as example sentences to help explain my point. The quotation marks around the word 'saying' is because  I was using the verb as a noun which isn't really a word. I used quotation marks to try and avoid confusion between the intended meaning of referring to the action and the actual noun that means a short common expression. If this doesn't answer your question please let me know